# Collatz Conjecture program randomly stops being accurate at high digits

Tags: python, math

So while Wikipedia surfing, I stumbled onto the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)  So I decided to write a simple python program,

```
while True:
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
n=0

 while True:
     if  (x % 2) == 0:
         x = x/2
         n += 1
         print(x)
     else:
         x = 3*x +1
         n+=1
         print(x)
     if x == 1:
        break
print("N = %d" %(n))
```

At first I played around with random numbers, and then I decided to test some of the larger numbers that the Wikipedia article represents. The program worked perfectly up until  75,128,138,247 on Wikipedia's " Examples" Section,previously it matched the number of steps exactly, and then it just randomly says "512" for N (the number of steps. I just don't understand why. Can anyone Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float division might cause issues (note output as floats), so work in integers:

change

```
x = x/2
```

to integer division (your `print` correponds to Python 3, so it is available)

```
x = x // 2
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.